# Console isn't outputting what I expect

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that will take a number, add it to itself over an over again.

For example:

- The random number is 6
- 0 + 1 = 1
- 1 + 2 = 3
- 3 + 3 = 6
- 6 + 4 = 10
- 10 + 5 = 15
- 15 + 6 = 21
- Output 21

This is my code:

```
int input = Console.Read();
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
{
    total += i;
}
Console.Write(total);
```

When I put in any number I get a huge number back. For example, inputting three returns 1326. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

to read a number from console. You are getting the ASCII code of the `3` char, which is `51`.

Basically the same as `(int)'3'` (gives `51`)

`Console.ReadLine()` reads a whole line from the console as a `string`. Then you call `int.Parse` to parse a number from that string.

So if you enter `3` and press `enter`, you'll get the same functionality as:

```
int input = int.Parse("3"); //input will have 3 as integer
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
{
    total += i;
}
Console.Write(total); //prints 6
```

**note**: consider using `int.TryParse`, because you never know if the input of the user can be represented as an integer. You'll get `FormatException` if you will pass wrong string into `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not read a decimal representation of an integer number represented as a sequence of characters (although its signature suggests otherwise). It reads a single character, and returns you its ASCII code.

The code of character `'3'` is 51; [the sum of numbers from zero to 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) is 51*52/2=1326, the number that gets printed.

Comment: It does "read" an `int` (of the raw stream). I think that part can be clarified a bit.